# What does the message "[Error] invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')" mean?

Tags: c, pointers, declaration, dereference

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
        
    int i,j=1;
    int *jp1,jp2 = &j;
    
    jp1 = jp2;
    
    i = ++(*jp2);

//  *jp2 = *jp1 +i; // [Error] invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')
    
    printf("i = %d,j = %d , *jp1 = %d , *jp2 = %d\n",i,j,*jp1,*jp2);    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have declared `jp2` as an `int`, not a pointer to int.  Try `int *jp1, *jp2 = &j;`

Comment: `*` goes with the variable, not the type.

Comment: Aaaand that's why cramming multiple variable declarations into one line is a ***bad idea***.  Whoever is teaching you to do that needs to improve.

Answer (score 4):

This declaration

```
int *jp1,jp2 = &j;
```

is equivalent to

```
int *jp1;
int jp2 = &j;
```

As you see you are trying to assign pointer `&j` to the variable `jp2` of the type `int`.

Also you may not apply the dereference operator `*` to an object that does not have a pointer type like

```
*jp2 = *jp1 +i;
```

Write

```
int *jp1, *jp2 = &j;
```

Though to avoid such an error it is better to write each declaration separately

```
int *jp1; 
int *jp2 = &j;
```